# Lisp custom comparison functions

Tags: common-lisp

Let's say I define a new class `foo`:

```
(defclass foo ()
  ((bar :initarg :bar ...)
   (baz :initarg :baz ...)
   ...))
```

And I want to create a custom comparator for `foo`, such as:

```
(defun foo-equalp (foo1 foo2)
  (equalp (bar foo1)))
```

Would there be a better, more explicit way to tie this `foo-equalp` function to the `foo` class?

I was thinking of not having to pass `#'foo-equalp` as the `:test` argument to functions like `REMOVE-DUPLICATES`, but even if that is not possible, I would still like to know if there is a more idiomatic Lisp way to define this function.

Comment: It sounds like you want an equality predicate that's a generic function to which specialized methods can be added (sort of like how  you can specialize `.equals()` in Java).  Unfortunately, none of the "common" predicates (`eq`, `eql`, `equal`, `equalp`) are generic functions, so while it's not too hard to write such a generic function, you'll still have to pass it to library functions like `remove`, etc., since it won't be the default comparison for those library functions.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Are you aware of http://cdr.eurolisp.org/document/8/cleqcmp.html ?  I've put together an implementation of CDR8, but haven't published it yet (need to clean it up and submit it).

Comment: @PaulNathan I was aware of the CDR Repository, but I hadn't read that particular one before.  It looks like a good idea.  I'd certainly upvote an answer that made use of it. :)  I realize that you said you hadn't published it yet, but is it available online anywhere in any state yet?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: https://github.com/pnathan/generic-comparability  (I also worked on CDR 2 implementations, but it's less baked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question then [generic functions](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-generic-functions.html) could help here

```
(defgeneric foo-equalp (foo1 foo2))

(defmethod foo-equalp ((foo1 foo) (foo2 foo))
  (and (equal (bar foo1) (bar foo2))
       (equal (baz foo1) (baz foo2))))
```

and now when you call foo-equalp with objects that are not of type foo you get this error.

```
There is no applicable method for the generic function
  #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION FOO-EQUALP (1)>
when called with arguments
  (1 2).
```

or you might want everything else to return nil

```
(defmethod foo-equalp ((foo1 t) (foo2 t))
  nil)
```

Here we specialize on [t which is the set of all objects](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_t.htm). When you call a method common lisp will always choose the 'closest/most specific' type match for the arguments (ugh that is a terrible mangling of a description..I need more coffee, check out the link as it is awesome **:)**)

- *You don't actually need to specialize of t as this is the default but I wanted to include it to show what was happening.*

---

The following are snippets from Practical Common Lisp *(which is linked at the top of this
answer)*

> A generic function defines an abstract operation, specifying its name
>   and a parameter list but no implementation. The actual implementation
>   of a generic function is provided by methods.
>
> Methods indicate what kinds of arguments they can handle by
>   specializing the required parameters defined by the generic function.
>
> For instance, for a generic function draw, you might define one method
>   that specializes the shape parameter for objects that are instances of
>   the class circle while another method specializes shape for objects
>   that are instances of the class triangle.

Comment: Use generic functions when you plan to extend it with several methods using inheritance and/or method combinations. Otherwise it might be overkill.

Comment: Cheers, I've always been a bit hazy on when to choose which technique. Nice to have this as a rule of thumb.